# Loading up all entities as part of an Aggregate Root

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

From what I've read online an Aggregate when loaded from the database must be in the complete state. Meaning it must have access to all the entities inside of it also loaded from the database so that the aggregate is never in an invalid/incomplete state.

What if the aggregate contains an entity of which there can be millions of for eg. `Aggregate A` contains `Entity B` and `Entity C`. Now worst case scenario there can be upto 100 `Entity B` instances under the `Aggregate A` but there can be millions (if not billions) of `Entity C` under `Aggregate A`.

---

**The Use Case:**

The use case would be that I want to remove one particular instance of `Entity C` from `Aggregate A` using an Id. To do this in the `DDD` fashion I would have to first load up the `Aggregate A` from the database and load all it's Entities into memory. and then remove the item maybe by using a method like below:

```
public class AggregateA extends AbstractAggregateRoot<AggregateA>{

     private String aggregateId;

     private Map<String, EntityC> entityC;

     public void removeEntityC(String idToRemove) {
           this.entityC.remove(idToRemove);
           registerEvent(new EntityCRemoved(aggregateId, idToRemove));
     }
}
```

---

**The question:**

Loading up millions of entities into memory to perform any `Write Operation (Command in CQRS)` for a single request doesn't seem the right way.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the "load the complete aggregate" mandate of DDD. Like you said, it's wholly impractical to do so. My recommendation is to load the complete parts of the aggregate that is needed.

For example: My action (albeit contrived) is to edit a specific blog comment in a blog entry with millions of comments. What I'll do is load the blog aggregate and the single comment I am trying to update from the repository. I'll then go ahead and have the blog aggregate update the comment. Ofcourse, another design choice would be to load just the comment (since you can identify it with it's id) but that would be loading an incomplete entity since it'd be missing the Aggregate root (that is what the mandate is telling not to do).

One issue here ofcourse is that it becomes in-efficient to do batch updates in DDD. That is a weakness by design and a problem solved outside of DDD.

Comment: Thanks, it does make more sense than the brckner's answer but now wouldn't there be an issue if let's say you have a domain invariant that no two comments can be the same (just as an example in continuation to your answer) . Now when you edit the blog comment, let's say that it's conflicting with another comment. Since you've loaded up only a single comment, you wouldn't know if it's conflicting with another comment unless you rely on the database for unique indexing. But the goal of the DDD was to keep all invariants as part of the Domain and not depend on Infrastructure to ensure invariants.

Comment: Good question. In your extended example: Your UL now requires the comment to be unique under a blog. So, your comment content is now a key. When your hydrate your blog (your aggregate), your repo needs to take the key (the content) and hydrate that as well. This is so because for the function you are trying to perform, "complete" means the repo hydrating the blog and any comment with the existing comment-key. So, you get a blog with a single comment, from the repo even before you run blog.add(comment). The rest is trivial from there.

Comment: I don't quite understand `hydrate` am I missing something? Would you be able to point me in the direction where I can understand this?

Comment: hydrate means when you pull it out of storage. So, when your blog post out of storage (probably database) to add a comment, also pull all comments that have the same key as the new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a first sign to rethink your aggregate boundaries. One possible solution would be to treat Entity C as an aggregate and have a reference by id to Aggregate A. It depends on your business domain, so this is only a vague recomendation. You could have a factory method in Aggregate A or in a seperate domain service which generates an instance of Aggregate C. In general you should avoid loading hundreds of Entities within an Aggregate, because it will span a huge transactional boundary arround that aggregate.

```
public class AggregateA {
    public AggregateC createAggregateC(...){
        //create AggregateC and return it with reference set to AggregateA
        return new AggregateC(this.id, ...)
    }
}
```

Comment: But except for the number of `Entity C` in `Aggregate A`, it's an ideal case for it to be an `Entity`. Some of them are: 1) It does not make sense for the `Entity C` to be there without `Aggregate A`. 2) If you delete `Aggregate A` all associated `Entity C` must also be deleted. 3) Any change to the `Entity C` must always take place via the `Aggregate A` since there are some Invariants that `Aggregate A` ensures on the `Entity C`. It would not make sense to break `Entity C` into it's own Aggregate to be honest

Comment: It depends on your business logic. It won't make sense to load thousands of entities within one aggregate, since your transactional boundaries will explode. 1) Why not? You will still will have a reference between them. 2/3) You could enforce such invariants through a domain service. 
I'm not sure, but I think Vaughn Vernon addresses some of your issues in this blog series. Maybe have a look there. 

https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: You're right on the scale part and that was the point of the question "Loading up a million instances of an entity associated to the aggregate" doesn't make sense. Would you be able to elaborate on your answer? Because I haven't read anywhere not can I find some resources on making an Aggregate a part of another Aggregate